# Input field japanese value needs to be replaced to english digit value

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I have a input field, which accepts numbers; on key press of digits in Japanese language; i need to replace them with corresponding english digits.

I'm using the below function but it is doing for single instance but for multiple entries is failing.

```
$('input[data-type=number], input[data-type=day]').keyup(function(){debugger;
    var inputVal = $(this).val();

    var result = '{"１":"1", "２":"2", "３":"3", "４":"4", "５":"5", "６":"6", "７":"7", "８":"8", "９":"9", "０":"0"}';

    $.each($.parseJSON(result), function(k, v) {
        console.log(k +' is '+ v);
        if(inputVal === k){
            inputVal = v;
        }
    });

    $(this).val(inputVal);
});
```

We need to keep intact the value which is already coverted. For example, if I type １ then it converts to 1 but when type in again １３, it stays as is in the input box.

Comment: Tried String.prototype.replaceArray but we cannot create a array for japanese digits

Answer (score 0):

This is, beacuse you are searching the whole input value in the array, but the array contains single values. So it will work with single digits this way.
You can use global replace for each value:

```
var str="１２３２２";
var n=str.replace(/１/g,"1").replace(/２/g,"2");
//n will be: 12３22
```

Maybe there is a more elegant way, but this should work.

It's woking on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHUHs/)

Comment: I put this onkeyup event but when i focusout from that field it returns back to japanese format... :P

Comment: In the Fiddle, type １２ then it changes to 12 but when you focusout or click outside(blur) it comes back to １２

Comment: Not for me, but I can only copy&paste your numbers, but it behaves the same way since ctrp+p also triggers the keyup event. But In my case the blur doesn't brings back the japanese value. I have no further idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `inputVal === k` check. You are trying to match the whole input value to a single character.

```
$('input[data-type=number], input[data-type=day]').keyup(function() {
  var inputVal = $(this).val()
  var inputLastChar = inputVal.substr(-1);

  var mapping = {
    "１": "1",
    "２": "2",
    "３": "3",
    "４": "4",
    "５": "5",
    "６": "6",
    "７": "7",
    "８": "8",
    "９": "9",
    "０": "0"
  }

  matchedChar = null
  $.each(mapping, function(k, v) {
    if (inputLastChar === k) {
      console.log(k +' is '+ v);
      matchedChar = v;
    }
  });

  if (matchedChar) {
    $(this).val(inputVal.substr(0, inputVal.length - 1) + matchedChar);
  }
});
```

Some notes:

- You don’t need to create a JSON string, and then parse it. You can just create object for matching, like in example above.
- My example is just a rewrite of original, so it also checks text in the input field, but it’s better to use another approach: check the input char from the event, and then insert the corrected value to input field. This will solve the issue of blinking chars in input field, and some chars not changed if you type fast enough.

Comment: Now if we input １３ then it is doing for last ones only １3